# Hola tengo problema en mi CAPA DE DATOS CON UN RETURN JSON C#

Tags: c#, visual, net, framework

[image: ME DICE QUE EL JSON NO EXISTE EN EL CONTEXTO ACTUAL]
HOLA BUENAS NOCHES TENGO UN ERROR EN EL RETURN JSON ME DICE QUE EL  JSON NO EXISTE EN EL CONTEXTO ACTUAL ESTOY USANDO NET FRAMEWORK VISUAL ESTUDIO C#

Comment: Buenas, Daniel, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Puedes incluir tu código como texto formateado? Y recuerda que las mayúsculas se considera que ESTÁS GRITANDO.

Comment: Si puedes indicar que version de .NET estas utilizando tambien para ayudarte mejor.  Pero tambien pregunta si estas en la capa de datos... ¿Esta capa esta separada en un proyecto de libreria? ¿O esta en el mismo proyecto de Web? Porque veo que estas devolviendo [JsonResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.jsonresult) y en la capa de datos lo ideal seria devolver la entidad o listado de tu "entidad de negocio", en tu caso la lista de "clientes"

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que `Json` es un método de `Controller` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2 y supongo que tu capa de datos no es parte del controller, sino que son clases a aparte que no heredan de `Controller`

Lo que funcionaría sería:

```
return new JsonResult { Data = lista };
```

O quizás:

```
return new JsonResult { Data = new {data = lista }};
```

Para hacerlo lo más parecido a lo que estás poniendo.

De todas maneras me gustaría decirte que una capa de acceso a datos no debería devolver `JsonResult`, porque eso es responsabilidad de los controllers. Lo que debería devolver la capa de datos son datos, en este caso una lista de clientes, luego el controller puede devolver un `JsonResult` a partir de esos datos.